# How to cherry-pick which columns to display in jQuery dataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

The JSON coming back from the server (used for populating the [dataTable](http://datatables.net/)) looks like:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "attributeType":{
         "id":1,
         "name":"test1",
         "tag":"test-type",
         "is-dog":false
      },
      "attributeValue":{
         "id":null,
         "name":"blah",
         "tag":"BLAH"
      },
      "buzz":1,
      "fizz":"53abc"
   }
]
```

However, I only want to display the following fields:

- `id`
- `attributeValue.name`
- `buzz`

And furthermore, I want them displayed in the following order (left to right):

- `buzz`
- `attributeValue.name`
- `id`

How can I configure my dataTable to select only these three fields, and to display them in the desired order? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do to achive this is build your table dynamically and then send this to the datatable.

In the following example I am assuming the Json is coming back in a jQuery Ajax call and you have multiple items in your response:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Controller Url",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
...
...
success: function (response) {

// Assuming you need to parse, you may not need to depending on how the data is returned.
var parsedJson = $.parseJSON(response); 
// Empty var to hold the table content.
var buildTable = "";

$.each(parsedJson, function(i)) {
    buildTable += "<tr>";
    buildTable += "<td>" + parsedJson[i].buzz + "</td>";
    buildTable += "<td>" + parsedJson[i].attributeValue.name + "</td>";
    buildTable += "<td>" + parsedJson[i].id + "</td>";
    buildTable += "</tr>";
});

// Now fill your datatable with the table content in the order you want and with only the fields required.
$("#datatableContent").append(buildTable);

// Configure your datatable
$('#datatableContent').dataTable({ });

} //end success

});// end ajax
```

In your View you would have:

```
<table id="datatableContent">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Buzz</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>ID</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
```

One thing to bear in mind is that I had problems if I placed the `$('#datatableContent').dataTable({ });` config part outwith the success of the ajax call. I have mines placed after the `$("#datatableContent").append(buildTable);` line within the success and it works perfectly every time.

Comment: Thanks @KDee (+1) - forgive me if I'm not understanding you here, but I don't see a dataTable (i.e. `$('#datatableContent').dataTable()` anywhere in your code snippet. It looks like you're building the HTML table with a jQuery `$.ajax()` call, but not with [dataTables](http://datatables.net/). If this is the case, I need to figure out how to do this with dataTables, not *just* jQuery. And if I'm misunderstanding you, can you please update the code to show where/how dataTables is used? Thanks again for such a great answer!

Comment: @pnongrata I've ommitted the dataTable part in the code as it would be based on your settings. As i mention above when you configure the datatable, you would do this after the .append line. So you would have something like: $("#datatableContent").append(buildTable);
            $('#datatableContent).dataTable({
                "aLengthMenu": [5, 10, 25, 50, 75],
                "bSort": true, ......
                ... other settings
             });
I use dataTables this way. The dynamic data is appended to the table.